# Standard normal distribution probability identity

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I thought it was a common or well-known identity of the function but it seems not. I barely found any mention of it on the web. So, I guess it'd be great if I could get an answer here for future reference too...

The distribution function is,

> $$\Phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{- \infty}^{x}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy, \text{   where } x \in \mathbb{R}$$

I am given the identity to prove

> $$\Phi( \lambda x)=1- \Phi(-\lambda x)$$

for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. While I proved the identity $\Phi(-x)=1- \Phi(x)$, I don't know if I should use that. I mean the RHS of the identity is sort of equal to LHS if I use it but it seems trivial.

My attempt was to simply go on with the integration,

$$\Phi(\lambda x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \int_{- \infty}^{\lambda x}e^{-\frac{y^2}{2}}dy= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}^{\lambda x}_{- \infty}[- \frac{1}{y} e^{- \frac{y^2}{2}}] $$

which if I take the limit $y \rightarrow -\infty$ the last term will limit to a $0$ (I hope I am right?) and so the equation reduces to

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}(- \frac{1}{\lambda x}e^{- \frac{\lambda ^2 x^2}{2}})$$

but I get stuck here as there seem nothing more I can do, certainly nothing I could fiddle with to get to $1-\Phi(-\lambda x)$.

Can someone please help me...? How do I prove this? Thank you in advance

Comment: $\phi(x)$ is not a density function, but distribution function!

Comment: Maybe it's the notation you're talking about? How do you type out capital $\phi$ in latex?

Comment: You defined $\phi$ as a integral of density, therefore $\phi$ is in your case distribution function, but on the fourth line you are saying it is density! Btw. $\Phi$.

Comment: Oh okay sorry, seems so...I looked again at my notes and I got muddled up, lemme fix it...and thanks for the capital phi too

Comment: Also your integration of $e^{-y^2/2}$ is not correct as it is well known, that  $\int e^{-y^2/2} dy$ cannot be written using known functions. Since you already know $\Phi(-x)=1- \Phi(x) ~ \forall x$, it is quite obvious $\Phi( \lambda y)=1- \Phi(-\lambda y)$ by just putting $x=-\lambda y$.

Comment: Aye the integral is wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a density function; $\phi$ as you have defined it is a cumulative distribution function.  The density function is the *integrand* $$f(y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-y^2/2}$$ and you have the relationship $$\phi(x) = \int_{y=-\infty}^x f(y) \, dy.$$  The identity to be proven is equivalent to $$\phi(\lambda x) + \phi(-\lambda x) = 1.$$  To this end, we observe that $f$ is an even function:  $$f(y) = f(-y)$$ for all $y \in \mathbb R$.  Therefore, $$\phi(x) = \int_{y=-\infty}^x f(-y) \, dy = -\int_{y = \infty}^{-x} f(y) \, dy = \int_{y=-x}^\infty f(y) \, dy.$$  Consequently, $$\phi(-\lambda x) = \int_{y=\lambda x}^\infty f(y) \, dy$$ and $$\phi(\lambda x) + \phi(-\lambda x) = \int_{y=-\infty}^{\lambda x} f(y) \, dy + \int_{y=\lambda x}^\infty f(y) \, dy = \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty f(y) \, dy = 1,$$ the last equality due to the fact that the integral of a probability density over its support is equal to unity.

Comment: Cheers! got it solved...